# Algorithms to indentify people in pictures without using face recognition

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, image-recognition

There are lot of researches about face detection in pictures, but is it the only way one can say "this person I'm looking for is here in this picture"? Aren't there algorithms that you can provide with information like lateral or back pictures of a person and making calculations on the height, the width, the anatomic distance between parts of its body, the analysis of the hair can determine: "there's a X per cent chance this is the person you're looking for"? Is it possible to accomplish?